# SSN Input Field with display only last four digits | with show/hide feature

Tags: jquery, css, bootstrap-5

I only want to display the SSN last four digits and rest in asterisk. Like : ****-**-7654

and I want to toggle asterisk show/hide. so that user can see behind the asterisk and toggle it.

```
            <input type="password" name="password" id="password" />
            <i class="bi bi-eye-slash" id="togglePassword"></i>
```

please help to sort out this

Regards

Comment: Are you sure you need to be collecting the SSN yourself? That's not something people take lightly, since it could be used for identity theft. I most likely, as the user, would be extremely hesitant to enter it, especially to a site owner that puts the SSN format with 10 digits instead of 9.

Comment: sorry It is 9 digits, its misspelled to 10.  correct is like that : ***-**-7654

Answer (score 1):

This may not work exactly how you're wanting but it will get you very close.
This code takes advantage of blur() and focus() on the input.
After typing in your full SS, click out of the input to see the changes.
Clicking submit will trigger the alert() which shows the full SS as you typed it.

```js
$('form').on('submit', function(e){
    e.preventDefault();
    let socialSecurityValue = $('input[name=social]').data('value');
    alert('SS: ' + socialSecurityValue);
});

$('input[name=social]').focus(function(){
    let val = $(this).data('value');
    if (val) {
        $(this).val(val);
    }
});

$('input[name=social]').blur(function(){
    $(this).data('value', $(this).val());
    $(this).val( $(this).val().replace(/^\d{5}/, '***-**-'));
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<form>
    <input class="social" type="text" name="social" maxlength="9" required>
    <input type="submit" value="Submit">
</form>
```

Comment: Thanks you very much for this great solution. Can you please tell me how can I use format like 000-00-0000 while input text.